# OSX terminal string length

Tags: bash

Is it possible in OSX's terminal to get the length of a string? Eg:

```
$ echo "foo".length
```

Or

```
$ echo (cat file.txt).length
```

Comment: `echo ${"foo"}` or perhaps `echo "foo" | wc -c`

Comment: So `echo ${"foo"}` returned `zsh: bad substitution` and `echo "foo" | wc -c` returned `4`!

Comment: Interesting.... echo "foo" | wc -c works on Linux (don't have a terminal to test at the moment)

Comment: I know I can use, eg, node: `node -p '"foo".length'` but I thought there must be a _native_ way, right?

Comment: And I would think that [wc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/wc.1.html) would be the way

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
echo "foo" | wc -c
```

This counts the number of characters on stdin. Note that this will return `4` since `echo` adds a newline at the end. Use `printf` or `echo -n` to avoid the added newline.

```
printf "foo" | wc -c
```

Comment: `printf "foo" | wc -c` does work, but I'm not sure why the response has whitespace (looks like two tabs then the number) rather than just the number.

Comment: That's strange. On my Ubuntu system `wc -c` simply prints `3`, no extra whitespace.

Comment: I'm on the fun time love storm that is OSX

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
var=hello; echo ${#var}
```

Comment: How can I do that without assigning a var?

Comment: You can't. Unfortunately assignment is required.

Answer (score 1):

expr length can be used

```
expr length "hello"
5
```

Comment: `expr: syntax error`

Comment: `length` is a GNU extension, not supported by all implementations of `expr`.

Answer (score 1):

From Mac OS Terminal, you can also use the Swift REPL to do so:

```
user_name% xcrun swift repl
Welcome to Apple Swift version 5.7.2 (swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51).
Type :help for assistance.
  1> print("foo".count) 
3
  2>
```

Comment: Not sure if there has been a change, but I think the command to use is: ```swift repl``` to experiment in Swift interactively

Comment: Or, just typing `"foo".count` in the REPL works too

Comment: In 2023, the Terminal command is: `xcrun swift`.  See: https://vrat28.medium.com/the-swift-repl-4c57cebfc5af

Answer (score 1):

Faster way if the string is in your clipboard.

```
pbpaste | wc -c
```

Comment: ... but i just copied this command...

Comment: Within your terminal (bash/zsh), you could ctrl+r to retrieve historical commands. Or even just typing once autosuggestion's setup. https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions

Answer (score 0):

The suggested solution adds 1 to the actual length. In my opinion, this is a better solution.

Added this to your .zshrc or .bash_profile

```
lenFunc() {
  echo ${#1}
}

alias len=lenFunc
```

Then

```
len foo
// output 3
```